# something about diffeomorphism

Tags: analysis, manifolds, differential-topology

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are both open sets, and there is a diffeomorphism $g$ between them. My book says that the chain rule implies that $Dg$ is non-singular. I don't understand. Can anyone tell my why?

Comment: What don't you understand? Your question is rather broad.

Comment: why chain rule implies that Dg is non-singular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Actually we notice composite of  g and g inverse is identity. Using chain rule on composite of g and g inverse we can get the conclusion.